# Onclick listener on recyclerview to display image

Tags: android

so far I have a click listener for my recycler view to display the content in the next activity but I'm trying to display the image on the next activity but it doesn't seem to help to load can anyone help me, please? I put the productactivity for context reasons the issue is the image isn't being sent to the next activity through the intent.

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SearchViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        //Loads the variables on to the recyclerview
        holder.name.setText(products.get(position).getName());
        holder.price.setText(products.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.year.setText(products.get(position).getYear());
        holder.location.setText(products.get(position).getLocation());
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(products.get(position).getImage1())
                .into(holder.image);
        //Onclick Listener to view all details of the car
       holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Create a new intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProductActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", products.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("price", products.get(position).getPrice());
                intent.putExtra("year", products.get(position).getYear());
                intent.putExtra("location", products.get(position).getLocation());
                intent.putExtra("mileage", products.get(position).getMileage());
                intent.putExtra("colour", products.get(position).getColour());
                intent.putExtra("image1",products.get(position).getImage1());
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Edited: added the productActivity for context reasons

```
public class ProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declare variables
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);

        //Assign variables
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.carIv);
        text1 = findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
        text2 = findViewById(R.id.locationTv);
        text3 = findViewById(R.id.mileageTv);
        text4 = findViewById(R.id.colourTv);
        text5 = findViewById(R.id.yearTv);
        text6 = findViewById(R.id.priceTv);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.carIv);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addToCart();
            }
        });

        //Create Bundle
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = bundle.getString("name");
        String location = bundle.getString("location");
        String mileage = bundle.getString("mileage");
        String colour = bundle.getString("colour");
        String year = bundle.getString("year");
        String price = bundle.getString("price");
        Integer image1 = bundle.getInt("image1");

        //Set name to textview
        text1.setText(name);
        text2.setText(location);
        text3.setText(mileage);
        text4.setText(colour);
        text5.setText(year);
        text6.setText(price);
        imageView.setImageResource(image1);






    }
```

Products.java

public class Products {
public String name, price, location, mileage, colour, year, image1, image2, image3;

```
public Products(){}

public Products(String name, String price, String location, String mileage, String colour, String year, String image1, String image2, String image3) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.location = location;
    this.mileage = mileage;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.year = year;
    this.image1 = image1;
    this.image2 = image2;
    this.image3 = image3;
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getMileage() {
    return mileage;
}

public void setMileage(String mileage) {
    this.mileage = mileage;
}

public String getColour() {
    return colour;
}

public void setColour(String colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getImage1() {
    return image1;
}

public void setImage1(String image1) {
    this.image1 = image1;
}

public String getImage2() {
    return image2;
}

public void setImage2(String image2) {
    this.image2 = image2;
}

public String getImage3() {
    return image3;
}

public void setImage3(String image3) {
    this.image3 = image3;
}
```

}

Comment: can you show us the model class of product

Comment: just added it there

Comment: `intent.putExtra("image1",products.get(position).getImage1());` here you put a string,  and here you are trying to get an int `Integer image1 = bundle.getInt("image1");`

Comment: oh ok  is there another way to set an image that takes a string instead of a int. for example instead of imageView.setImageResource(image1); what could I use ?

Comment: setImageResource for showing the image which is in the drawables directory, Since you are using glide to load the image it seems like the image is from a remote place, so use glide to load that image.

Comment: ok ill try that thanks

Comment: hi i tried it and it's not displaying is there any other way to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
String image1 = bundle.getStringExtra("image1");
```

then for loading Image to the ImageView.

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(image1)
     .into(imageView);
```